# Can't assign contravariant object

Tags: c#, contravariance

I created the following SuperNode:

```
public interface ISuperNodeWrite<in T, in TNode> where TNode : ISuperNodeWrite<T, TNode>
{
    T Data { set; }

    TNode Left { set; }
}
public class SuperNode<T> : ISuperNodeWrite<T, SuperNode<T>>
{
    public SuperNode()
    {

    }
    public SuperNode(ISuperNodeWrite<T, SuperNode<T>> bla)
    {
        Left = bla;

    }
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public SuperNode<T> Left { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```
        SuperNode<BaseData> m1 = new SuperNode<BaseData>(new SuperNode<ExtendedData>()); //not compileable
        m1.Data = new ExtendedData();
        m1.Left = new SuperNode<ExtendedData>(); //not compileable
```

Does anybody know how to achieve the above?

Comment: Does the type of node really need to be known?  Does someone calling the interface's method to get the next node in the chain need to care what type of node it is, other than that it implements the interface?

Comment: @Servy The idea was to create a typesafe linked list which take use of generic contravariants. Does this answer your question?

Comment: No.  Do you actually need the implementing type, or is it enough to simply know that the next node implements the interface?

Comment: Its enough to simply know that the next node implements the interface. I would prefer that.

Comment: So the problem won't be solvable because that interface is conceptually invariant, not contravariant.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're asking. I can't in good faith post an answer, because I'm not 100% sure about how to explain it, but: your example seems to be an attempt to combine the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern with contravariance. First, I think it's important to point out that your `SuperNode<T>` class isn't legal. You can't use the interface type as the constructor parameter, because you can't assign that type to `SuperNode<T>`. More generally, variant type parameters reverse their sense if you use the type in which they are found as a variant type parameter. ...

Comment: ... Usually, this is fine because the type graph is acyclic. But in the CRTP, the type parameter winds up getting reused in its own position. This means the variant parameter has to be both contravariant and covariant at the same time, which in turn just means not variant at all. I _believe_ that this means that variance can't work at all with the CRTP; the two patterns are just mutually exclusive of each other.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It's not that all variance doesn't work with the pattern, it's just that contravariance doesn't work.  Covarinace works just fine.